# How to separate combinatorics in a loop?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

Lets say I have 4 locations, `x = rand(4,1)`. For each location I would like to calculate the distance to each of the other 3 locations, `d = pdist(x, 'euclidean')`. This gives me 6 unique distances, eg. 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34.
How do I separate these combinations, such that I get all distances from respective location 1, 2, 3 to the others. So the results should look like:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5]
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`squareform`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) is what you're after. It unpacks all distances into a square, symmetric matrix:

```
>> x = rand(4,1)
x =
    0.5290
    0.5673
    0.4487
    0.9872
>> d = pdist(x, 'euclidean')
d =
    0.0383    0.0802    0.4582    0.1186    0.4199    0.5384
>> D = squareform(d)
D =
         0    0.0383    0.0802    0.4582
    0.0383         0    0.1186    0.4199
    0.0802    0.1186         0    0.5384
    0.4582    0.4199    0.5384         0
```

so for example `D(2,3)` (or `D(3,2)`) is the distance from point 2 to point 3.

Comment: Yes this seems more straight forward. And then combined with
`for n = 1:Num-1 
    D(n,(n+1):end)
end`

Answer (score 0):

Create an index with all the 6 combinations, `idx = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`. Remove respectively the first 3, 2, 1 elements in this index for each loop (`idx(1:Num-n) = []`).

```
Num = 4;
idx = 1:nchoosek(Num,2); % index of all combinations
for n = 1:Num-1 % loop through all except last
    idx(1:Num-n) % print
    idx(1:Num-n) = []; % remove the first elements in index
end
```

This will give the following result

```
ans = 1     2     3
ans = 4     5
ans = 6
```